# HttpSession (active session) on Tomcat (newRelic information)

Tags: tomcat, kubernetes, newrelic, httpsession

We have a stateless application, running on tomcat with Kubernetes. I'd like to understand why New Relic is showing that we have more than 50k active HTTP sessions. Even if we destroy/restart all the images, the number of active sessions is still high.

Where is the origin of this information?

Example: [image: graph in New Relic]

Comment: Can you add more details and graphs about this information? You can also contact New Relic support.

Comment: Thanks Rico! I've added an image with the specific graph. It's a springboot application running with Kubernetes. All the requests are made by another application using some http client. I've read the documentation of new relic but there is not enough information about my issue: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/browser/new-relic-browser/page-load-timing-resources/session-tracking